# Run vba code on Form_Load of new form but only if previous form has a specific name

Tags: ms-access, vba, form-load

I would like to have a button to open a form and then run VBA code on that form. So either using Form_Load or and intermediate module. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use [`OpenArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836583.aspx).

First form:

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm "SecondForm", OpenArgs:=Me.Name
```

Second form:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()

    If Me.OpenArgs = "FirstForm" Then
        ' Stuff
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare a module level variable in the second form:

```
Dim Prev As Form
```

In the On Load-event of the second form (this sets a reference to the first form):

```
Set Prev = Screen.ActiveForm
```

And in the On Close-event:

```
Set Prev = nothing
```

Now you can check the name of the previous form with:

```
If Prev.Name = "..." Then
    ... your actions
End If
```

Furthermore you can check any property or field from the first/previous form this way. Prev is acting like Me now.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say the new form be opened from a number of forms in your application;

Can more than one of the calling forms be open at any one time?

If not, use this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    If isLoaded("Form1") then
        Form1_InstructionSet
    ElseIf isLoaded("Form2") then
        Form2_InstructionSet
    ...
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_InstructionSet
    ...
End Sub

etc.
```

If more than one of the calling forms can be open simultaneously, you should parameterise the new form, as per @Andre's answer above.